# Trying to figure out promises in javascript

Tags: javascript, promise

I was reading [this article](https://medium.com/javascript-scene/master-the-javascript-interview-what-is-a-promise-27fc71e77261#.bx2sjopnu) and i reached this piece of code:

```
const wait = time => new Promise((resolve) => setTimeout(resolve, time));
wait(3000).then(() => console.log('Hello!')); // 'Hello!'
```

Unfortunately, this example didn't really help me to understand this power of promises everybody is talking about.. I was wondering what's the difference between the above code and this one -

```
setTimeout(() => { console.log('Hello!'); },3000);
```

Comment: the difference is, the first code returns a promise and is useable in a Promise chain

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no functional difference between the two examples you show - they generate the same result.  Your promise example was just showing you how to use promises with `setTimeout()`.

The power of promises comes when you have more complicated scenarios such as multiple asynchronous operations you want to coordinate, sequential async operations, error handling in async operations, etc...  The example you show is probably the simplest possible use of promises and thus does not show off its capabilities or the more valuable scenarios in which you would use it.

Here are some of the scenarios where promises are massively more useful:

**Sequencing multiple async operations with proper error handling**

```
doSomethingAsync1().then(doSomethingAsync2).then(doSomethingAsync3).then(results -> {
    // handle final result here
}).catch(err => {
   // handle error here
});
```

**Coordinating multiple Asynchronous Operations so you can run them in parallel and know when they are all done**

```
Promise.all(doSomethingAsync1(), doSomethingAsync2(), doSomethingAsync3()).then(results => {
    // all results available here
}).catch(err => {
     // handle error here
})
```

**Handling complicated async error conditions**

```
doSomethingAsync1().then(result1 => {
     if (result1 passes some condition) {
         return doSomethingAsync2().then(r => {
             // process result here
         });
     } else {
         return doSomethingAsync3().then(r => {
             // process result here
         });
     }
}).catch(err => {
    // all async errors will propagate to here
});
```

Ah, and all these `.then()` handlers are "throw-safe" which means if an exceptions occurs in any of the asynchronous `.then()` handlers, it will automatically be caught and turned into a rejected promise which can easily be handled in the `.catch()` handler in all my examples.  Try writing that code with regular callbacks (no promises).  You would have to put try/catch yourself around every single callback in order to make then "throw-safe".  If you didn't do that, any exceptions throw in async callbacks would probably be silently eaten by the system.

Comment: So the ability to sequence these async operations into a synced chain is its' actual power.. I think i get it now.
In your second example, does the .all method try to resolve the doSomethingAsyncN() chain in the order that it was passed to it (async1 then async2 then async3 and so on..) without them (the promises) relying on each other?

Comment: @DavidJones - That's just the tip of the iceberg, but enough all by itself to justify using them.  There's a lot more to it.

Comment: Thanks! For some reason i was sure that i already clicked the green checkmark. thanks for noticing me.